# Can you give some websites tutorials or books about series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, convergence-divergence, power-series, uniform-convergence

I need more practice in deciding if the series converges or diverges in using ratio tests, Cauchy-Hadamart`s tests and so on. Please, recommend me something worth.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply can use Khan Academy`s courses to deepen your skills 
https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus-home/series-calc
and for practice use this book http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~vybiral/MAII-2016/Demidovich-Problems-in-Mathematical-Analysis.pdf

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help.